# Find "Similar" Part Numbers

Tags: sql-server, ascii

I hope you'll find this interesting!  C# is the preferred language for solutions, or T-SQL.

Consider the following items:

Item 1: NJ2-12GM50-Wö-V13

Item 2: NJ2-12GM50-Wo-V13

You can guess that the individual entering Item 1 copied and pasted, and the individual entering Item 2 just used 'o', the closest english character he could find.

When somebody enters a new part number like NJ2-12GM50-Wo-V13, we want to suggest to them that they might mean NJ2-12GM50-Wö-V13.

In order to do so, we want to convert all characters that can be stored as a VARCHAR back to their simplist lower case letter.  I'm interested in a solution that converts, for example, ASCII character 246 (ö) to ASCII character 111 (o).

The idea being that if we make a lookup column containing all the converted versions of the partnumbers, we can easily match them to keyboard entry.

Of course, I can make a Dictionary to do it, but I wonder if there is a smarter way.

Thanks!

Comment: As mentioned below, you should consider how far off a user is allowed to go. A simple e vs. é is one thing. But "close" numbers is another. As a point of interest, spell checkers (which of course do this type of thing for a living) use SOUNDEX (or its big brother, double metaphone). But that's getting serious ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably your best bet is to implement a function in either C# or T-SQL to calculate the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) between the two part numbers.

Comment: Is this not overkill? Surely a simple "COLLATE" would do it especially in SQL

Comment: @gbn - Perhaps. Depends on the types of differences. Yes, if the only difference is `o` vs `ö`, then collate will do assuming Latin languages and assuming that system finds a match in collate'd result and assuming no other differences exist such as a missing character.

Comment: This was very helpful, and I appreciate the suggestion.  I didn't mention that we have 11,000,000+ rows of part numbers.  What we ended up doing was "tokenizing" (for lack of a better word) each part number into 4 character sequences... so ROCKY is 'rock' and 'ocky.'  We put all possible 4 character sequences into a "Tokens" table and created a many to many table called ItemsTokens, that has a composite key on both IDs.  A trigger keeps the items tokenized.  That gives us too many results, but FAST.  Then we use Levenshtein on the initial results to throw out matches that are not near enough.

Answer (score 2):

Use the COLLATE clause to coerce the strings to both case and accent insensitive

```
IF 'NJ2-12GM50-Wö-V13' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI
       =
   'NJ2-12GM50-Wo-V13' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI
      PRINT 'matches'
ELSE
      PRINT 'no match
```

So, you can use it something like to validate user input

```
SELECT
   PartNo AS DidYouMeanThis,
   @Input AS WhenYouEnteredThis
FROM
   MyPartNumbers
WHERE
   PartNo COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI = @Input COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI
```

using a different COLLATE you can then ensure an exact match on write...

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SLECT * FROM MyPartNumbers
            WHERE PartNo COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN = @Input Latin1_General_BIN)
   RAISERROR ('Oi! I asked DidYouMeanThis', 16, 1)
ELSE
   INSERT ...
```

Comment: Probably the simplest solution assuming Latin characters and assuming the use of an international character is the only difference.

Comment: This was a great suggestion as well, and got my vote.  Thanks!  Unfortunately, we have too many items (11,000,000+) to compare each string, and we are not using exact matches.  However, once we tokenized the part numbers (see comment above) we can use COLLATE to match tokens derived from the incoming string against that Tokens table without having to do a bunch of ugly String.Replace operations first.  Works great with just a handful of exceptions in the ASCII character list... maybe 5 or so, which we just handle individually.

Answer (score 1):

I can't add this as a comment for some reason, but you may consider, instead (or as well as), a matching of "commonly searched for" mappings. Such a system would probably be useful in general (i.e. "red hanger -> AB-999X", etc) and may solve this problem for you. Worth considering, anyway.

Comment: This will be extremely helpful actually for mapping things that are KNOWN to be "equivelant."  For example, You may have MyCompany Ltd, MyCompany Limited, MyCompany Ltd., MyCompany Limited., MyCompany Limted (typo) etc... all of these Ltd, Limited, Ltd., etc... on the end of a company name are EQUAL, and we'll have to account for that.  Good comment, thank you!.